# Is smoke required for Techies to kill Roshan in early levels?

Tags: dota-2

I have seen a video of Techies killing Roshan at level 8 with Arcane Boots, Soul Ring etc, in that video he first uses Smoke of Deceit to disappear and then he did that trick.

Is there any connection with the smoke thing and that trick working or not?

Comment: Can you post the video URL here.?

Comment: Pradip try to search on google and you will find in first top links..as links are too big so cant paste here

Comment: killing rosh will bring a benefit of ~200gold per player while you need a huge time to do that. Better mine him so that the enemy team can't get him. And kill other players :)

Comment: Is this the video you saw? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sO4RKiIHcuw

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Smoke of Deceit (Dust of Appearance is an item that shows invisible units, I always say the wrong thing as well) is a common item to use when going for a Roshan kill.

This is because Roshan can be a huge advantage for a team so the enemy team will generally keep the entrance warded so they can contest Roshan, maybe killing the enemy team or just chasing them away and taking Roshan for themselves.

The thing with Techies killing Roshan does not depend on Smoking to go in, however it is a cheap way of making sure you can't be *seen* going in so no one will attack you while you're being half killed by an angry monster thing.

Comment: thnx for that  info but my main qus is that this trick is working or not?

Comment: Yes, you can solo kill Roshan with Techies. No, smoke is not required for killing Roshan, it might be required for surviving the attempt.

Comment: ok thanx but i think you din get my point..first do you know that trick with mana boot and soul ring?

Comment: This one? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sO4RKiIHcuw or this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_JYl0iics2o&ab_channel=Dota2PERU Yes. I would hesitate to call them viable but they are possible.

Comment: Kevin is spot on. You don't need Smoke to do the trick, but if you're playing against opponents that have any idea what they're doing, they won't let you approach Roshan that easily. You'll need a smoke (and good timing) to avoid the detection they most likely have laid out around the Roshan pit.

Comment: @rahmu yes i got it but i thought mana trick will work with smoke but :( its not working any more..:(

Comment: Smoke does nothing for mana. It is completely irrelevant. - The "mana trick" works, because when you pick up the arcane boots it increases mana so you have the same percentage of mana in your pool. If you soul ring while not wearing boots you fill up more than you fill up more percent of your mana pool than with the max mana increase from boots.